# Adding header to new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating a temperature logger program that records date, time, and temperatures. The program should create a new .csv file that includes data and column headers. However I'm finding it difficult to add headers to the new file. I tried using two while loops, one before the other and the file didn't seem to append the headers, but recorded the data OK. Then I tried to nest in an `if` statement and it wrote the headers but also added them to the end of every new line of data (see picture below).

My code is as follows:

```
datetime1 = str(datetime.now())

#create new file with datestamp
extension = ".csv"
file_name = datetime1 + extension
file1 = open(file_name, 'a')

#add header to .csv
header = str("Date,Time,Minutes,InletTemp,ControlTemp,BedTemp,OutletTemp")

#x = 1
#while x >= 1:
#    file1 = open(file_name, 'a')
#    file1.write(header)
#    x -= 1

#start button function
def start():
    while(1):
        x = 1
        if x >= 1:
            file1 = open(file_name, 'a')
            file1.write(header)
      
            
#gather the data from each thermocouple
        t1 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,1)
        t2 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,2)
        t3 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,3)
        t4 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,4)

#themoplate LED cycle
        THERMO.toggleLED(0)
        
#write sensor data to a file
        datetime2 = datetime.now()
        data = str(datetime2) + ',' + ' ' + str(t1) + ',' + str(t2) + ',' + str(t3) + ',' + str(t4)
        file1 = open(file_name, 'a') 
        file1.write('\n')
        file1.write(data)
        
#write sensor data to the console
        print (str(datetime2))
        print ('Temperature on Channel 1:',t1)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 2:',t2)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 3:',t3)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 4:',t4)
        time.sleep(1)
```

`while` loop with nested `if` statement:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You only want to write the header to a file once.  If you're opening a new file, you don't want "append" mode.  Just use "w".  And remember it is pointless to call the `str()` function on something that's already a string.

Comment: Thanks Tim, yes in one of my many iterations of this code I was getting a tuple error for some reason and that's why I tired to cast as a string. But yes, you're correct I changed it and its still a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `x=1` at the beginning of the while(True) loop and it is never updated, that's why it gets added every line.

I think you should, first open the file in write mode, something like:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file1:
    file1.write(header)
```

which will erase previous data and write your header. And then you open the file once before the while(True) in append mode as you were doing (`file1 = open(file_name, 'a')`).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is closer to what you want.  This leaves the file open continuously.  If you don't like that, do `file1.close()` after printing the header, and `file1=open(file_name, 'a')` before writing the data and `file1.close()` after.

```
datetime1 = str(datetime.now())

#create new file with datestamp
extension = ".csv"
file_name = datetime1 + extension

#add header to .csv
header = "Date,Time,Minutes,InletTemp,ControlTemp,BedTemp,OutletTemp"

#start button function
def start():
    file1 = open(file_name, 'w')
    print(header, file=file1)

    while(1):     
            
#gather the data from each thermocouple
        t1 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,1)
        t2 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,2)
        t3 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,3)
        t4 = THERMO.getTEMP(0,4)

#themoplate LED cycle
        THERMO.toggleLED(0)
        
#write sensor data to a file
        datetime2 = datetime.now()
        data = ','.join( (str(datetime2), str(t1), str(t2), str(t3), str(t4) )
        print( data, file=file1)
        
#write sensor data to the console
        print (str(datetime2))
        print ('Temperature on Channel 1:',t1)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 2:',t2)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 3:',t3)
        print ('Temperature on Channel 4:',t4)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're re-opening and re-headering your file after every line, meaning the header gets concatenated to the end of every line. To fix this, fix your while-loop, like so:

```py
def start():
    x = 1
    while 1:
        if x == 1:
            file1 = open(file_name, 'w')
            file1.write(header)
            file1.close()
    # ...etc
```

That way, you only write the header exactly once when the loop starts, and not every time a reading is recorded. I also recommend calling `close()` every time you finish writing to the file.

Comment: Or you could do that outside the loop, and you don't really want 'a' mode, and he is still mismanaging the newlines.

Comment: @TimRoberts You're right, fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution is to use the `csv` module to write the data.  Open the file once at the beginning to write the header, and then append new data as collected:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import time


now = datetime.now()
filename = f'sensors_{now:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}.csv'

# Write mode to start a new file
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow('Date Time Minutes InletTemp ControlTemp BedTemp OutletTemp'.split())

def start():
    while True:
        # Simulate data
        t1,t2,t3,t4 = 45.1,45.2,45.3,45.4

        # collect column data in a list
        now = datetime.now()
        row = [now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),now.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'),'',t1,t2,t3,t4]

        # append new data
        with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)

        # Write sensor data to the console
        print(now)
        print('Temperature on Channel 1:',t1)
        print('Temperature on Channel 2:',t2)
        print('Temperature on Channel 3:',t3)
        print('Temperature on Channel 4:',t4)
        time.sleep(1)

start()
```

Example output:

```
sensors_20211028094726.csv:

Date,Time,Minutes,InletTemp,ControlTemp,BedTemp,OutletTemp
2021-10-28,09:47:26.710602,,45.1,45.2,45.3,45.4
2021-10-28,09:47:27.718613,,45.1,45.2,45.3,45.4
2021-10-28,09:47:28.734657,,45.1,45.2,45.3,45.4
2021-10-28,09:47:29.750682,,45.1,45.2,45.3,45.4
```

Comment: Mark, This looks much cleaner, and I wasn't aware of the csv module. Thanks for pointing that out, I will test it in my next version.

Comment: @pequalsmv The `csv` module handles proper quoting and escaping of fields that contain string quoting characters or delimiters such as comma as well.  It's a much better option that writing the csv lines manually.

Answer (score 0):

import csv  # at the top of your program

Then use a [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to build the CSV. That will put in the headers for you.

Comment: Assuming he had a set of dictionaries, which he doesn't right now.

Comment: I don't know what that means. You don't need "a set of dictionaries" to use DictWriter.